# How to put Show / Hide Icon inside input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, field

I have an input field type password, I'm trying to put show / hide icon inside it. The problem is the icon, it is actually another input field and with html I can't put an input field inside another input field.

Can someone help me ? Maybe with css there can be a solution?
Sorry but I'm not very good with this, I appreciate any answer, thanks.

```js
function showPassword() {
  var x = document.getElementById("password_current");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
  }
```

```css
/*Toggle Password class*/
#togglePw { display: none; }
#togglePw + label:before { content: "\f06e"; }
#togglePw:checked + label:before { content: "\f070"; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">

<p class="">
  <label class="t2" for="password_current"></label>
  <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password" id="password_current" autocomplete="off"/>   <input type="checkbox" id="togglePw" onclick="showPassword()"/> 
  <label for="togglePw" class="fa"></label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using absolute positioning to align the icon.

Wrap the two inputs (password & checkbox) in a div.

```html
<div id="password-input-toggle">
  <input id="your-password-field"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="your-toggle-checkbox"/>
</div>
```

```css
#password-input-toggle {
  position: relative;
}

#your-toggle-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use some CSS to nudge it left a little, not forgetting to allow for padding on the input control so text won't cover it.

```js
function showPassword() {
  var x = document.getElementById("password_current");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```css
/*Toggle Password class*/

#togglePw {
  display: none;
}

#togglePw+label:before {
  content: "\f06e";
}

#togglePw:checked+label:before {
  content: "\f070";
}


/* add these: */

#togglePw+label {
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#password_current {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">

<p class="">
  <label class="t2" for="password_current"></label>
  <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password" id="password_current" autocomplete="off" /> <input type="checkbox" id="togglePw" onclick="showPassword()" />
  <label for="togglePw" class="fa"></label>
</p>
```